# ASP MVC - Problem of persistence of session variable when using fetch

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, fetch

In my project ASP MVC Framework.net 4.6, I have got a strange problem with session variables.

When I update my variable with a view and get, post controller, everything is working.

**View test.cshtml**

```
...
<form id="frm" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="foo"  value="OK"/>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
...
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult test()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
public ActionResult test(Formcollection fc)
        {
            Session["foo"] = "UPDATED AT " + DateTime.Now;
            return View();
        }
```

Like this,  session["foo"] is readable and reachable in all the project with its updated value. This method  works.

The problem is that when I want to POST my DATA with javascript fetch, I can reach my controller HttpPost Test (see above), certify that the variable Session["foo"] is well updated in debugger mode,
but Session["foo"] is not updated in all other part of my project..(other views and controllers).?

It seems as the 2 methods doesnt work on the same variable .

Please can someone help me ?

Here is the js fetch code run by a click button in test view.

```
async function PostDataFoo() {

fd = new FormData();
fd.append('foo','UPDATED AT ' + Date());
   

const res = await fetch("/test", {
        method: "POST",
        body: fd
        
    });
alert('The end');   
}
```

Comment: You need to add `credentials: 'include'` to your `fetch` options - doing that will mean `fetch` will use cookies.

Comment: Thx. I tried with include, but it does not work. It is incredible...the same method httppost test works when it is called by a submit in the view, but does not when it is called by fetch...really strange ....another idea ?

Comment: What does your browser's DevTool's Network tab say?

Comment: Thx Dai.. The network tab says nothing abnormal...the response after the fetch is OK (status 200) ...no errors in the console..

Comment: Incredible, I found the solution after hours of tests and investigations.
I want to share this solution with the readers/members of this site.

The problem was in the url of the fetch. I just included the root of the site ...here is the right fetch.

fetch('/mysapplicationsite/Home/test', method: "POST",body: fd).

What is incredible, it is that with a wrong url, I can run the post  method in the controller, but the variable session is not updated..unbelievable !

I hope this will help some readers of this post.